# How to handle constants and file paths contants in C# project correctly

Tags: c#

Im trying to figure out the most elegant way to handle various types of constants in my C# application.
I have, for example, some string constants that are shown in UserControl's
I also have some constants that are file path to some .xml configuration files.
What is the best approach for localization support in the future for my actual strings, and what is the best approach for my currently declared constants such as `private const string xmlFilePath = @"Configuration\someFile.xml";` ?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to mention - Im using WPF

Answer (score 4):

What I do in my projects is I have a separate class project, with a class that holds my constants. What's nice about this approach is that if I need to change a constant, I don't need to recompile my main program. I only need to recompile my constant project and then I can upload just that DLL to my production server.

The only caveat that you need to watch out for is that you need to make them `readonly` instead of `const`. Like this:

```
public readonly string XmlPath = @"Configuration\SomeFile.xml";
```

The reason is because constants are treated like copy and paste in a word processor. The compiler will look up the value of your `const` variable, then paste the result into your program, then compile your program with the pasted result inside the executable. This means that if you changed the value of your constant, you'd have to recompile every project dependent on that constant.

By making it `readonly`, you are telling the compiler not to simply paste the value into your program, but instead, look up the value when needed during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a single file called Aliases.cs in my solutions where I store a few static classes specifically for hard-coded values.  I like to keep it fluent if I can without abbreviations or cryptic names.

This makes it really easy to later change a "hard-coded" setting into a config variable without trying to use find-replace and you can cross-reference it so you can see all the places you use your `MagicNumbers` for example.

**Aliases.cs**

```cs
namespace SolutionName.Classes
{
    public static class MagicNumbers
    {
        // Hardcoded Optional Values (tweakable without serious side-effects)
        public const int Max_Backups = 10;
        public const int Max_Console_Line_History = 1000;

        // Hardcoded Configuration settings (Changes will break logic, if you don't know what it's for)
        public const int Important_Foo_Bar_Setting = 1234;
    }

    public static class ConfigSettings
    {
        /*Never, ever change these constant string values!!! REQUIRED for backwards compatability!*/
        public const string VERSION_1_0 = "FooBar V1.0";
        public const string VERSION_1_1 = "FooBar V1.1";
        public const string VERSION_2_0 = "FooBar V2.0";

        /*This reference should be updated to the most recent VERSION_#_# constant defined above.*/
        public const string CURRENT_VERSION = VERSION_2_0;
    }

    public static class Folders
    {
        //Top Level Folders
        public const string Backups = @"\Backups";
        public const string Bin = @"\Bin";
        public const string Logs = @"\Logs";
        public const string Resources = @"\Resources";

        //Sub Folders
        public const string Reports = Bin + @"\Reports";
        public const string Old_Logs = Logs + @"\Old";
    }

    public static class FileTypes
    {
        public const string tmp = "~tmp";
        public const string dat = ".dat";
        public const string csv = ".csv";
        public const string txt = ".txt";
        public const string npp = ".npp";
        public const string iscfg = ".iscfg";
        public const string bkp = ".bkp";
        public const string xml = ".xml";
        public const string png = ".png";
        public const string tkn = ".tkn";
    }

    public static class Pattern
    {
        public const string WildCard = "*";
        public const string Date_yyyy_MM_dd_Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        public const string Time_HH_mm_ss_fff_Format = "HH:mm:ss.fff";
        public const string Logfile_Timestamp_Format = Date_yyyy_MM_dd_Format + " " + Time_HH_mm_ss_fff_Format;// "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering localization, you should use a resource file for each supported culture. This will generate satellite assemblies specific to each culture:

[image: Localization with resources files]

Then use this kind of XAML markup:

```
<Window
  ...
  xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:OrderTaker.Properties">

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.OrderWindow_Title}" />
```

This will automatically insert the localized string for `OrderWindow_Title` depending on the application's CurrentUICulture.

Important: Do not forget to set the access modifier to `public` in the resx definition windows.

For the application specific strings such as your xml files paths, I would store them in the App.config file, making them completely independently deployable. Create a new Settings File named `AppSettings` in the Properties folder (you'll have to create it in the project root and then move it manually) and mark the scope of each value you define in there as `Application` (instead of `User`) in the key/value editor. Then access it in your code like that:

```
Console.Write(Properties.AppSettings.Default.xmlFilePath);
```